# Can't create container in Azure blob storage with the same name as a deleted container

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage

I'm writing some python code against Azure Blob Storage and running into something that appears to be a bug.

I've been doing some debugging and in the process I've created and then deleted and then created again a container with the same name several times.  This has worked fine through most of the day, however suddenly the call to create the container started returning false, and not creating the container.

I'm creating the container using create_container() with the only parameter being the container name, and I'm deleting the container using the Azure portal.  When my code runs it first checks for the existence of the container, and if it doesn't find it, attempts to create it.

Since this worked for most of the day, I'm wondering if it's some sort of synchronization issue in the underlying Azure filesystem, or some other invisible thing?

Any suggestions, troubleshooting tips, etc. are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although this is an old thread, I had the same question a few days ago, and wanted to post my findings:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179431.aspx states under the **Exceptions to Default Timeout Interval** section:

> A container that was recently deleted cannot be recreated until all of its blobs are deleted. Depending on how much data was stored within the container, complete deletion can take seconds or minutes. If you try to create a container of the same name during this cleanup period, your call returns an error immediately.

Comment: Just as a follow-up for anyone else running into this issue, I found in Python that the create_container() method didn't return an error, but rather returns `False`. As such, you need to keep retrying the method until it returns `True`.